# Smallest rectangle to put the 24 ABCD words combination

Tags: optimization, polyomino, packing

Put in the smallest possible size board all combination of 4 quantity of letters. Crossword must be connected. And can be only 4 letters words. Cannot be words with 2, 3, 5 or more letters

Example for:

ABC = 3 letters = 6 combinations in a 3x3 square

[image]

Here is a solution for ABCD = 4 letters = 24 combinations in a 12 x 12 square = 144

[image]

I am sure it is possible a solution in a smallest area rectangle

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> \begin{matrix}      &1 &2 &3 &4 \\    1 &A &D &B &C \\    2 &C &B &D &A \\    3 &B &A &C &  \\    4 &D &C &A &B \\    5 &  &  &  &A \\    6 &A &B &D &C \\    7 &C &A &B &D \\    8 &D &D &C & \\    9 &B &C &A &D \\    10 & & & &C \\    11 &C &D &A &B \\    12 &A &A &B &A \\    13 &D &B &C &  \\    14 &B &C &D &A \\    15 & & & &D \\    16 &B &D &C &C \\    17 &D &A &D &B \\    18 &A &C &B &  \\    19 &C &B &A &D \\\end{matrix}

Second attempt, based on suggestion from @Rodolfo Kurchan:

> \begin{matrix}      &1 &2 &3 &4 \\1&&B&&C\\2&&D&&B\\3&&C&&A\\4&B&A&C&D\\5&A&&D&\\6&D&A&B&C\\7&C&D&A&B\\8&&B&&D\\9&D&C&B&A\\10&A&&C&\\11&C&A&D&B\\12&B&C&A&D\\13&&D&&A\\14&D&B&A&C\\15&B&&C&\\16&C&A&B&D\\17&A&B&D&C\\18&&C&&A\\19&A&D&C&B\\\end{matrix}

Comment: Hi, in the solutions can be only 4 letter words, in this solution there are some 3 letter words

Comment: You can try a similar solution in this board

1)XXXOOOOXOOOOXOOOOXO
2)OOOOXOOOOXOOOOXOOOO
3)XXXOOOOXOOOOXOOOOXO
4)OOOOXOOOOXOOOOXOOOO

Sorry I don´t know how to show in 4 different lines

Comment: Excellent solution.
But now Bryce Herdt suggest to find a solution in this 5x15 rectangle of area 75 instead of the 4x19 rectangle of area 76

1) OOOOXXXXOOOOXOX
2) XOOOOXOOOOXOOOO
3) XOOOOXOOOOXOOOO
4) XOOOOXOOOOXOOOO
5) XXXXOOOOXXXXOXO

Answer (score 17):

Pretty sure that the following is minimal.

> [image: All Permutations]

Comment: Wow welcome to Puzzling Stack Exchange, glad to have you here!

Comment: Welcome Ed, nice to see you.

Comment: It may not be minimal, but it certainly is elegant! The rotational symmetry is fairly neat!

Answer (score 1):

I believe this 7x5 minimal answer satisfies the requirements of the problem as stated (all combinations of 4 letters and connected), employing the fact that, for example, the string "abcda" contains both "abcd" and "bcda":

[image: Minimal solution to containing all four-letter combinations of a, b, c, and d]

Comment: Hi, in the rectangles can be only 4 letters words. Cannot be words with 2, 3, 5 or more letters

Comment: @RodolfoKurchan OK, I'll leave this here as a solution to the problem as originally written, though. I do believe the solution by Ed Pegg might very well be optimal for your additional requirements.

Answer (score -1):

```
abcd  cabd  cbda  bacd  dbac
   cbad  bcad  bdac  adbc  d
dcba  badc  acbd  dacb  acdb
   bdca  adcb  cbda  cadb  a
```

Oops!  It has duplicates.  27 sets not 24.

Comment: A 4x19 solution has already been posted (see the top accepted answer)

Comment: The 4x19 accepted answer has 3 letter words. On of the stipulations was no words length 2,3,5 or more.

Comment: Check its second spoiler block